# Calculating averages using AVERAGEIF , when the values in the range are inserted via formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some data I am trying to calculate averages of. Each "item" in the data set is stored in a different row, with the "type" of item being stored in column B. For ex.

[image]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C-sSB_SeHZhXXyEEawrLGi9flBO8CBX18qPJ3A4CPH8/edit?usp=sharing) also is a sample sheet I've created to demonstrate

Each column contains a different stat for that item, which I am trying to average in a summary section of the sheet.

The formula `=AVERAGEIF(B1:B, "Shirt", L1:L)` works well to calculate these averages when the value of the cells is a number directly inserted in the cell, but for some of these cells, the value is calculated via a formula. AVERAGEIF doesnt seem to play well with these cells, as it always gives me a `#DIV/0` error. The formulas are things like

`=SWITCH(C1, "Cap", "$50", "Sweatshirt", "$115","Shirt", "$175", "", "")` (which auto fills the sale price column based on the "type" listed in the C column, or

`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(N1)),IFERROR(O1/E1, ""),"")` (which calculates a rate by dividing my profit column by the hours column depending on if column N has a value)

Now, the results of each of these formulas IS a number to anyone reading the sheet, but Sheets doesnt see it as that when trying to use AVERAGEIF. How can I tell it to convert the values to a number before trying to average them? Or is there a better way to calculate averages that would work here?

Answer (score 0):

*The issue seems to be not because the values are inserted via formula but the way/style you are using them inside switch(). `"$50"` OR `"$175"` are text-based. just use them directly as numbers as such:*

```
=SWITCH(C1, "Cap", 50, "Sweatshirt", 115,"Shirt", 175, "", "")
```

*and then use `Format` > `Number` > `Currency` to give them the `$` look for that column*

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to fix it, still getting DIV/0 errors when I try

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: Sure thing, heres the sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C-sSB_SeHZhXXyEEawrLGi9flBO8CBX18qPJ3A4CPH8/edit?usp=sharing

You can see that average hours is easily calculated, as the hours are entered as numbers into the cell. The average price though, gives an error

Comment: I applied the above proposed **switch** formula change in the test sheet and it looks good to me now!!